# select statement in go and the selected case

Tags: go

I have a code https://play.golang.org/p/y5FGVfXdzC3, and trying to understand why second case is selected and not the first one.

Here is the example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "log"
)

func foo1() string {
    log.Println("foo1 evaluated")
    return "quick thing"
}

func foo2(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    c <- "sleepy thing"
}

func main() {
    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)
    
    go foo2(c2)

    select {
    case c1 <- foo1():
        fmt.Println("received", <-c1)
    case msg := <-c2:
        fmt.Println("received", msg)
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 foo1 evaluated
received sleepy thing

Program exited.
```

I would expect the first case to be "faster", because we are ready to send to c1, but it's not true and second case is selected. Could you please help me to understand this scenario?

Comment: Sending and receiving on channels are blocking operations. If you send on a channel and no one is receiving it the program would just dead lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) (emphasis mine):

> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1. For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and **right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement**. The result is a set of channels to receive from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. **Any side effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any) communication operation is selected to proceed.** Expressions on the left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or assignment are not yet evaluated.

So, you're seeing `foo1 evaluated` because `foo1()` gets called before a `case` is chosen. This does not mean that the first case was selected - in fact, per the output, the second case was selected, otherwise `received sleepy thing` would not have been printed.

The first case cannot be selected because `c1`'s send and receieve are in the same goroutine (the one running the `select`) and it is unbuffered.

Answer (score 1):

Case for channel `c1` will never be selected, because there is no goroutine reading from `c1`. A channel will be selected only if it is ready to read/write. In this case, `c2` is ready to be read from, because there is a goroutine waiting to write to it. If you create another goroutine reading from `c1`, then both  `c1` and `c2` will be ready, and one of them will be selected.

The message `foo1 evaluated` prints, because the case is evaluated immediately (i.e. foo1 is called), but the case is blocked before the value is sent to the channel.

Comment: I think the question is more why "foo1 evaluated" is being printed, which is because all cases are evaluated immediately, regardless of which is selected.